# Jboss 7 need alternative JRE

Tags: java, jboss

Have a problem. Before start server jboss 7.1.1, I have a problem:

```
**Error:** JDK 1.7 (or earlier) should be specified either as project SDK or 
alternative JRE
```

I am using jdk 1.8 In project. And I can use only 1.6 JRE for working with JBOSS.

If I used 1.8 at project, and 1.6 jre with jboss, I take error with unsupported major.minor version 52.0.

Can I change jdk for JBOSS on 1.8? And how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the posting below on the JBoss developer developer forum.

The short version is that you would need to backport various bug fixes to JBoss AS 7 in order to get it run on a Java 8 JRE.  It would be better / easier to upgrade to Wildfly.  (He says.)

---

> Re: AS 7 on Java 8 by Tomaz Cerar Apr 8, 2015 6:18 AM (in response to Matija Vizintin)
>
> Any big reason you cannot upgrade to WildFly 8?
>
> Core issue that prevents boot of AS7 on JDK8 is
>   https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2057
>
> which was fixed by
>   https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/commit/fa93ceff49c3e84851cb8b00157e4fbed1d2cdb7
>
> You could apply this commit to
>   https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/releases/tag/7.2.0.Final-testsuite-fix
>   tag and rebuild it.
>
> but, this will only make sure server starts on JDK8, there ware
>   handful of other fixes / changes that we needed to address to make
>   sure testsuite passes properly.
>
> In any case, i would recommend you to go with WildFly 8.2.0.Final.

Comment: What if I want to make it work with jdk 1.6 only, then how to start th server?

Comment: Make what work on JDK 1.6?  JBoss AS 7?  My understanding is that AS 7 works on Java 1.6 with no problems.  See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-Requirements  (I hope that you realize that Java 6 and JDK 1.6 refer to the same version of Java ....)